# Google web search api to get number of results with php

Tags: php, google-search-api

for keyword selection (seo)I need to know only the number of results for specific group of keywords. got this code from google https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/), but no way. PHP version is 5.6

```
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=relax&userip=MYIP";
$referrer = "http://localhost:8080/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($body);

in this case ... no results at all
I tried other ways ... eg.:

$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=relax";
$body = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($body);
$results= $json->responseData->cursor->resultCount;
```

in this case I got some schizophrenic results (sometimes I got numbers, sometimes I got nothing)... in any case always under the declared limit of 1000.
any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.